Can I keep the same Node ID (PeerId) in Helia - libp2p across restarts? I am using helia implementation of IPFS
Can I keep the same Node ID (PeerId) in Helia - libp2p across restarts? I am using Helia implementation of IPFS. Helia documentation really doesn't provide enough info on this. Helia forums also dones't have any info on this
Persist NodeId across every Restart

peerId generating by private key.
Look at the source code
https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/blob/635283461e87399c5cde6e729c4b993188e10168/packages/libp2p/src/index.ts#L41-L48
Here we see, that we should generate private key.
Try this
import {generateKeyPair, privateKeyFromRaw} from "@libp2p/crypto/keys";
import {Key} from "interface-datastore";

const KEY_NAME = new Key('privateKey');
export async function getOrCreatePrivateKey(datastore: FsDatastore) {
    try {
        const keyData = await datastore.get(KEY_NAME);

        // Key deserialization
        const privateKey = privateKeyFromRaw(keyData);

        console.log('Private key loaded from datastore.');
        return privateKey;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Private key not found, generating a new one.');

        // Generating a new key if it is not in the datastore
        const privateKey = await generateKeyPair('Ed25519');

        // Serialization and saving of a new key
        await datastore.put(KEY_NAME, privateKey.raw);

        console.log('Private key saved to datastore.');

        return privateKey;
    }
}

const libp2pNode = await createLibp2p({
        privateKey: await getOrCreatePrivateKey(datastoreCommonNode),
...

In this function we check if the private key exists, if not we generate a new one and store it locally. Thus, we have a persistent peerId.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
